# Polymorphism, operators overloading

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading

Let's say I have a class PArr which stores an array of various classes StringWrapper, FloatWrapper, IntWrapper- all of them derive from a base class Wrapper.

It's PArr class:

```
class PArr{
private:
    Wrapper** _wrappers;
    int _size;
public:
    PArr(int size);
    Wrapper& operator[](int index);


};
```

And here's the implementation of this class

```
#include "PArr.h"

PArr::PArr(int size){

    _size = size;
    _wrappers = new Wrapper*[_size];

}

Wrapper& PArr::operator[](int index){

    return _wrappers[index];
}
```

And here's the class for example FloatWrapper

```
#pragma once
#include "Wrapper.h"

class FloatWrapper : public Wrapper{
private:
      float* _floatPtr;
public:
      FloatWrapper(float number);

};
```

My main method looks like this:

```
int main() {  
     PArr a(3);

     a[0] = new FloatWrapper(0.1);
}
```

I get an error:
"no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Wrapper' and 'FloatWrapper*')

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The implementation of the class will also not compile.   The `operator[]` returns a `Wrapper &`, but `_wrappers[index]` is of type `Wrapper *`.    The mistake you're making is assuming that references and pointers are interchangeable.   They are not.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, or perhaps even correct, it'd be nice if you marked it as an accepted answer, upvoted it or both. If it wasn't any good, you should say so and maybe it'll get improved.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of stating the obvious: your `operator[]` is returning a `Wrapper&`, which is a *reference* type, and you're trying to assign a `Wrapper*`, a *pointer* type to it. This ain't gonna work.

If you rewrote your main function slightly, say like this:

```
int main()
{  
  PArr a(3);
  auto k = a[0];
}
```

you might find the error more informative:

> main.cpp: In member function 'Wrapper& PArr::operator[](int)':
>
> main.cpp:27:27: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'Wrapper&' from expression of type 'Wrapper*'
>
> ```
> return _wrappers[index];
>
>        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> ```

You might try something like this instead:

```
Wrapper*& PArr::operator[](int index)
{
  return _wrappers[index];
}
```

which does compile and let your original `main` run, at least for me. I make no further promises.

Finally, this answer isn't the place to go into the deeper problems with your code (use smart pointers, use standard library container classes like `array` or `vector`, consider things like `std::any` or `std::variant`), but, y'know, you should read up on those things.